# How redux-toolkit batches state updates on async functions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

You can say I'm kind of new to redux but I have used it before but never fully understood how things work behind the scene especially incase of async functions. but I know how it works in general. like how we dispatch an action and the state updates and I know the rules behind updating the state and how reducers are pure functions and all the async logic is done using thunks and all.

But I want to know how the cycle of state update happens. I know I don't fully understand it that is why I'm having problems in my code cause sometimes the state is what I think it will be and sometimes it is not mostly in async cases.

I have checked stackoverflow for questions like these and sometimes it's hard to find a pretty good answer anywhere but if anyone knows if this question has been answered they can point me to that link or if someone knows how it works can you please explain to me ?

Thanks any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually it's really just a big state machine. Action gets dispatched, state changes. Components and other subscribers get notified.

With async actions, the entire thing just pauses for a while (waiting for a promise to resolve etc.). Before and after the pause, it does the same things as with simple actions: dispatch an action, change state, notify subscribers.

Think of a vending machine that dispenses soft drinks. You push the button for "coke", this immediately "dispatches" an action, the state of the machine changes to "selected product = coke" (whereas before it was null or something). But now the machine also waits for you to put a coin in, which takes an unknown amount of time. As soon as you do that, the "promise" is resolved and another action is dispatched. As a side effect, the soft drink is ejected, and "selected product" goes back to being null.

Maybe it would help you to take a look at the general event loop paradigm in js. But the tl;dr is that it's a big state machine that you can program to wait for things before it continues to turn its gears.

Here's some pseudo-ish code to illustrate this:

```
const initialState = {
  selectedProduct: null
};

const vendingMachineReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SELECT_PRODUCT') {
    return { selectedProduct: action.payload };
  } else if (action.type === 'COINS_INSERTED') {
    return { selectedProduct: initialState.selectedProduct };
  }

  return state;
};

// This thunk action is dispatched by pressing a button in some React component.
const purchaseProduct = (productName) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_PRODUCT', payload: productName });

  // Some React component that uses state.selectedProduct would now immediately show
  // that the user wants "coke".

  // Now we wait and don't continue until the product was paid.
  // The execution leaves this function and lets the JS event loop deal with other things.
  await coinSlot.waitForRightAmountOfCoins(productName);

  // We resume right here once the promise above is resolved.
  productDispenser.ejectProduct(productName); // Side effect that ejects the paid product.
  dispatch({ type: 'COINS_INSERTED' });

  // Now the machine is back in its initial state and waits for the customer to select a product.
};
```

Comment: I understand your idea but my question is what would happen if we have a notification like your coke is getting dispatched and then the state of the notification resets to null so how would the first state update affect the second one ? That is where my confusion started.  Anyways THANKS for answering mate

Comment: @Athulkal The first state update (selected product -> "coke") does not affect the second one (selected product -> null) at all. It is the code in the async thunk action that orchestrates all of this. Meaning it does what you, the developer, want it to do. I'll add some pseudo code to my answer. Let me know if this helps.